# Message.content.split() Discord.PY

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a few commands that might have more than one value that I need to split a message for. Then problem is I want to be able to give the user the option to only use 1 value or up to 4. When I use `message.content.split(" ", 4)` I get an Index error because it's expecting 4 values. Is there an easier way to do this?

```py
  if message.content.lower().startswith('!rip'):
        x = message.content.split(" ", 4)
        riptext = x[1]
        riptext2 = x[2]
        riptext3 = x[3]
        riptext4 = x[4]
        rip = discord.Embed(color=random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF))
        rip.set_image(
            url=f"http://www.tombstonebuilder.com/generate.php?top1={quote(riptext)}&top2={quote(riptext2)}&top3={quote(riptext3)}&top4={quote(riptext4)}&sp=")
        await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=rip)
```

Comment: indexes start at 0 !

Comment: do you still have the problem after fixing your index ? Also why are you using 4 different variables ? why not just use x[0],x[1] directly ?

Comment: @penta i have to keep the index 1-4 or else it uses "!rip" as the first value. But i still get an indexerror if I use less than 4 values.

Comment: Use ```http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display``` to visualise & debug your code, i think you can use slicing to ignore the first !rip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice the `split()` output to ignore the first item (`'!rip'`) using:

```
message.content.split(" ",4)[1:]
```

Then, you can pad it with empty strings in case the length is smaller than 4.

Note that there's no need for individual variables `riptext1`, `riptext2`, etc. You can just make `riptext` into a list and access eg. the first element with `riptext[0]`:

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('!rip'):
    # store arguments in x, excluding the first element (!rip)
    x = message.content.split(" ",4)[1:]
    # pad x with empty strings in case there are less than 4 arguments, and store the result in riptext
    riptext = x[:4] + ['']*(4 - len(x))
    print(riptext)

    rip = discord.Embed(color=random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF))
    rip.set_image(
            url=f"http://www.tombstonebuilder.com/generate.php?top1={quote(riptext[0])}&top2={quote(riptext[1])}&top3={quote(riptext[2])}&top4={quote(riptext[3])}&sp=")
    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=rip)
```

For example, if `message.content = '!rip 1 2'`,

- `x` will be `['1', '2']`
- `riptext` will be `['1', '2', '', '']`

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. I knew I had to add len() in there somewhere to count the number of items but wasn't sure how to approach it. This works great